# putting sql-query response directly to foreach-loop?

Tags: php, iterator, pdo

Is there any reason to not do this?
Putting the query directly inside a `foreach`-statment when the only time the result is going to be used is within that location..

```
<select>
<?php foreach($dbh->query('SELECT id, name, so FROM Employees ORDER BY so') as $e): ?>
    <option value="<?=$e['so']?>">-- after "<?=$e['name']?>" --</option>
<?php  endforeach;  ?>
</select>
```

It seems like I don't have to provide the `fetchAll()` when doing so either.
In fact, if I just do the following, and not adding any `fetch()`-methods at all, I still get the result if I put `$employees` into a `foreach`-loop:

```
$employees = $dbh->query('SELECT id, name, so FROM Employees ORDER BY so');
foreach($employees as $e){  /* works same as above */  }
```

when I do `print_r($employees)`, I only get this string:

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id, name, so FROM Employees ORDER BY so )
```

Is that correct behaviour?

These are my options for the connection:

```
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES utf8',
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,  //  _SILENT (pub) || _WARNING || _EXCEPTION  (dev)
            );
```

Comment: For an explanation of why you can use the `query()` call inside the `foreach` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41426713/1575353). @YourCommonSense kind of explains this [in phpdelusions.net](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is very bad, for many reasons.

- your query could fail. It will result in a torn design, with only half the page rendered.
- sometimes you must display a different text if the query returned no rows
- sometimes you need to send your data in a different format. For example not as HTML, but as a JSON-formatted array in response to AJAX call.
- a bowl of spaghetti made from HTML, PHP and SQL makes it hard to maintain. There should be a separation between the data manipulation and the data presentation.

> These are my options for the connection:

Some of them are wrong as well

- a cargo cult persistent connection [will do you no good](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql#donts)
- charset should be set in the DSN
- ERRMODE should NEVER be set to silent. On a live server is should be the same as on dev, i.e. set to EXCEPTION. Errors should be only hidden from a site user, not completely silenced.